# How to calculate the lower limit of a div and scroll to the next div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, mousewheel

I'm trying to scroll to the next div when the current div almost came to its lower limit.

I'm using the jQuery plugin MouseWheel. The following code that I have, run the animation scrollTop when I scroll. But not when it reaches a certain desired point that would be its lower limit. Because, some div contain a lot of text with images.

This is the structure HTML

```html
<html>
[...]
<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="item">
      [Only a Image]
      <!-- Only a Img? I'm 2px distance to the next div OK, ScrollTop When Scroll1 -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      [Some Text]
      <!-- mmmm Some text. Ok, I let you read this.. Scroll 1.. Scroll 2.. Scroll 3.. 
      Wait! I'm 40px distance to the next div ... scrollTop -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      [Some text with Image]
      <!-- mmmm Some text with Image. Ok, I let you read this.. Scroll 1.. Scroll 2.. Scroll 3.. Scroll 4... Scroll 5.. Scroll 6..
      Wait! I'm 40px distance to the next div ... scrollTop -->
    </div>
    <div class="item">
       [....]
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the JS:

```js
$('#main').on('mousewheel', '.item', function(e) {
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(e.currentTarget).next().offset().top
        }, 1000);

    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(e.currentTarget).prev().offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the hight of the element to the offset

```
 $('#main').on('mousewheel', '.item', function(e) {
           if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $(e.currentTarget).offset().top+$(e.currentTarget).height();) {
             $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $(e.currentTarget).next().offset().top;
             }, 1000);

           }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```